# C - Array of pointers to string

Tags: c, pointers

How to do in C - array of pointers to string? 
Because the string is represented as array of chars i tried to do this:(assumes every string is maximum 10 chars and the array size is 100)

```
char[10]* array[100];
```

but it is wrong

Any suggestion?

Comment: Take a look to your `main` function. There you have exactly that for the `argv` parameter (`char**` or `char* argv[]`).

Comment: you mean this is the right answer?
char *argv[]

Comment: _One_ of the right _answers_

Comment: One (often difficult) thing you need to wrap your head around: you can have array of pointers (here pointers to arrays of char, possibly of different length, or pointer can be NULL too). Then you can have array of arrays (here of char) that is two dimensional array, where each inner array exists (can't be NULL) and has fixed length ('\0'-terminated string can be shorter, with unused space after the 0). With strings, you usually want the first, array of pointers to arrays of char.

Answer (score 2):

As Adriano said, in C, the main function contains an array of strings:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{ [...] }
```

`argv` is an array of strings, and is properly declared.
Copy that.  (and if you run into problems, ask a *specific, detailed* question)

Answer (score 0):

For static allocation:

```
char buf[10][100];
```

For dynamic allocation:

```
char *buf[10];
```

And assign thereafter:

```
buf[5] = strdup("Hello");
```

Comment: you mean char *buf[100]; don't you?

Comment: The "for dynamic allocation" version can be static too: `const char *arr[] = { "str1", "str2" };`